# Play video on Scroll, but stop page from moving

Tags: jquery, scroll, html5-video

I have this code to play a video as the user scrolls (the video stops playing when they stop scrolling), but I want to stop the page from scrolling until the video has ended and am not sure of how to achieve this.

```
(function() {

  var window_height   = $(window).height();
  var document_height = $(document).height();

  var video  = $('.landing #video-bg').get(0);
  var length = 19; //seconds

  var start = window_height;
  var end   = document_height - start;

  $(document).on('scroll', function () {   
    var position = $(document).scrollTop();
    var percent  = (position/end);

    var currentTime = length*percent;

    video.currentTime = currentTime;
  });
})();
```

What I want is to stop the page from scrolling, even though the user scrolls. So basically, the user scrolls, and the scroll plays and pauses the video, and then once the video has reached the end, then the normal page scroll resumes.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class such as "playing" to the video when the video is playing and use CSS to fix it in position:

```
video.playing {
    position: fixed;
}
```

And then remove the class when it isn't playing

Comment: Maybe I hadn't been clear enough. If I simply fix the video, the rest of the page still scrolls. What I want is to stop the page from scrolling, even though the user scrolls. So basically, the user scrolls, and the scroll plays and pauses the video, and then once the video has reached the end, then the normal page scroll resumes.